# Is this Coq proof correct?

Tags: coq

I'm sudying a solution to an exercise from the Software Foundations Volume 1. online book:
https://x80.org/collacoq/ozavikeyeh.coq

```
Example and_exercise : forall n m : nat, n + m = 0 -> n = 0 /\ m = 0.
Proof. 
    intros [|n] m H.
    - split. 
        + reflexivity. 
        + apply H.
    - inversion H. 
Qed.
```

Following `apply H` this is the proof state:

```
1 subgoal
n, m : nat
H : S n + m = 0
______________________________________(1/1)
S n = 0 /\ m = 0
```

The hypothesis `H` can't hold and neither can `S n = 0` be proved; is this proof still correct?

Comment: If Cos accepts your proof then it is correct, if it doesn't accept it, there is something wrong with it.

Comment: Théo, the subgoal S n = 0 /\ m = 0 is based on the false hypothesis H: S n + m = 0. How can then be the original claim proved in a meaningful way?

Comment: There's no problem with proving a false statement with a false statement (`S n + m = 0`) as a premise.

Comment: Of course it is, while you have a false hypothesis you can prove any arbitrary goal, since false implies anything.

Comment: If the hypothesis can't hold, you can use "discriminate H".

Answer (score 0):

You are making a case by n.
So you must accept that `S n + m = 0` holds otherwise you can't make cases.

To be more precise, you are proving that `S n = 0 /\ m = 0` holds under the assumption that `S n + m = 0` holds. It doesn't matter that `S n + m = 0` actually holds or not.

And `S n = 0 /\ m = 0` holds because `S n + m = 0` is a contradiction. Anything can happen under the contradiction on Logic. You can say anything while you don't care if it is inconsistent, right?